# msbuild calling powershell script under windows 7 gets signing error

Tags: powershell, msbuild, windows-7

We have a powershell build script that calls out to other scripts that is giving me trouble under Windows 7 64 bit.  It works fine under XP.  I've run set-executionpolicy to RemoteSigned (and also tried it with Bypass and Unrestricted).  I can pull the command line from the error message and run it myself and it all runs fine.

Build errors look terrible here; but I'm including them anyway for completeness.

---

```
Project "C:\dev7\Source\DashPortal\DashboardGenerator\DashboardGenerator.csproj" (2) is building "C:\dev7\Source\DashPo
rtal\DashboardController\DashboardController.csproj" (15) on node 0 (default targets).
  File C:\Users\pmckinney.NA\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 cannot be lo
  aded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "g
  et-help about_signing" for more details.
  At line:1 char:2
  + . <<<<  'C:\Users\pmckinney.NA\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

  File C:\dev7\Source\DashPortal\DashboardController\..\..\..\Build\createReportI
  nstallScript.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled
  on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
  At line:1 char:87
  + C:\dev7\Source\DashPortal\DashboardController\..\..\..\Build\createReportInst
  allScript <<<<  -t C:\dev7\Source\DashPortal\DashboardController\..\..\..\Sourc
  e\DashPortal\DashboardReports\ReportSetupScriptTemplate.sql -l C:\dev7\Source\D
  ashPortal\DashboardController\..\..\..\Source\DashPortal\DashboardReports\Repor
  tSetupReportList.xml -c C:\dev7\Source\DashPortal\DashboardController\..\..\..\
  Source\DashPortal\Config
      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

C:\dev7\Source\DashPortal\DashboardController\DashboardController.csproj(265,5): error MSB3073: The command "powershell
 C:\dev7\Source\DashPortal\DashboardController\..\..\..\Build\createReportInstallScript -t C:\dev7\Source\DashPortal\Da
shboardController\..\..\..\Source\DashPortal\DashboardReports\ReportSetupScriptTemplate.sql -l C:\dev7\Source\DashPorta
l\DashboardController\..\..\..\Source\DashPortal\DashboardReports\ReportSetupReportList.xml -c C:\dev7\Source\DashPorta
l\DashboardController\..\..\..\Source\DashPortal\Config" exited with code 1.
```

Comment: To maximise the use of a MSBuild script task, it might be worth getting a certificate to sign them with, this will avoid needing to enable non-signed scripts on every build system.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just guessing: You did run `Set-ExecutionPolicy` in your **x64** PowerShell and the build runs the **x86** PowerShell?

Maybe try Get-ExcutionPolicy in both shells.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: oops, I see you already enabled scripts. It's possibly something to do with the context under which MSBuild is running. Are you running MSBuild as a local service account of some kind?

Edit2: It's clear the error message is deceptive. There's something else going on and the execution policy error is being thrown but not for the expected reason. Perhaps as a way to isolate, try creating another MSBuild task that runs the same line but with shorter, hardcoded paths instead of the `/../../../` bonanza above?

Comment: I've got Set-ExecutionPolicy to RemoteSigned right now.  I've also tried Unrestricted and Bypass with no luck.

Comment: Yeah my bad, edited answer. For the record I have no idea what's going on :)

Comment: Actually, you were really close.  See the answer from Filburt.